# Breakpoints ignored in Qt Creator with CMake

Tags: debugging, cmake, qt-creator

I use Qt Creator with CMake not for Qt but as IDE. I can use CMake feature from inside Qt Creator to generate plain C++ projects. It compiles just fine and I can run it. But I'm encoutering a weird problem while debugging. I added the CMake argument -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug to my Build Settings and when I press the Debug Button, I have no errors. It even raises a segmentation fault if there is one. However, when I set breakpoints, these are just ignored as if I am in release mode, even if they appear in QtCreator. However, when I tried to debug a Qt project, breakpoints weren't ignored and the value of the variables appeared. I tried to reinstall Qt Creator and CMake but it didn't change anything.

**Did anyone already encounter this issue ?**

Additional informations :

- Qt Creator version 4.3.0
- CMake version 3.9.0
- Windows 10
- MinGW 5.3.0

.

Comment: Have you tried this: [Qt Creator Docu: Debugging a C++ Example Application](https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-debugging-example.html)

Comment: Yes I tried this. It worked very well but it's a Qt Project : it doesn't use CMake.

Comment: The link I've posted does not even refer to QtCreator projects nor CMake. It's absolutely independent of the build system.

Comment: Ok sorry, I thought you wanted me to test the procedure with the TextFinder example. Anyway, with a plain C++ projet using CMake, I can set breakpoints and remove them like at step 1 and 4 but when I press F5, the program doesn't stop at breakpoints and consequently doesn't display the variables and objects in the Locals and Expressions view.